# PHP Count number of Cookies with Specific Value

Tags: php, cookies, count

I'd like to count the number of cookies with a specific value in this case the value is 'complete' but the cookie key's will be unique. So there might be `key1 = complete`, `key 2 = complete` but I can't seem to find anyway to do `count($_COOKIE["ONLY THE VALUE"]);`

I'm sure its obvious but after days of trying to figure out how I've hit a stump.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

```
$count = array_count_values($_COOKIE);
echo $count["complete"]; // gives you the count for that value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `foreach` to go through the `$_COOKIE`

[foreach manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
$counter = 0;

foreach($_COOKIE as $value)
{
  if($value == "some val")
  {
      ++$counter;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`count(array_search("complete", $_COOKIE))` should work.  I have not tried it however.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
count(array_unique($_COOKIE));
```

Comment: That will only return the number of unique values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_count_values`

```
$cookie_count = array_count_values($_COOKIE);

echo $cookie_count ["complete"] ;
```

More info on array_count_values can be found here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Another approach would be :

```
$string = implode(',', $_COOKIE);
$cookie_count = substr_count($string, 'complete');
echo $cookie_count;
```